# "documentRef" is not a valid DocumentReference showing while updating a field

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to count the number of notification. My database structure is **Users/userId/notification/doc**. I want to keep track number of the notification. My code is

```
notificationCount: async (change,context) => {
        const countRef=db.collection("Users").doc(context.params.userID);
        let increment;
        if (change.after.exists && !change.before.exists) {
          increment = 1;
        } else if (!change.after.exists && change.before.exists) {
          increment = -1;
        } else {
          return null;
        }

    return db.runTransaction((transaction) => {
      return transaction.get(countRef).then((sfDoc) => {
        if (!sfDoc.exists) {

          return transaction.set({
            notifications: 0
          }, { merge: true });
        } else {
          var newNotification = sfDoc.data().population + increment;
          return transaction.set({
            notifications: newNotification
          });
        }

      });
    }).then(() => {
      console.log("Transaction successfully committed!");
      return null;
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log("Transaction failed: ", error);
    });

  }
```

But I'm getting error

```
    at Object.validateDocumentReference (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:1810:15)
    at WriteBatch.set (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:241:21)
    at Transaction.set (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/transaction.js:182:26)
    at transaction.get.then (/srv/counter.js:71:30)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is in two places:

```
      return transaction.set({
        notifications: 0
      }, { merge: true });
```

And here:

```
      return transaction.set({
        notifications: newNotification
      });
```

You have to call out a specific document to update when calling [transaction.set()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Transaction.html#set).  As you can see from the linked API docs, the first argument to set() must be a DocumentReference type object, but you're passing a plain old JavaScript object.  Perhaps you meant to use the document reference `countRef` that you used to read from the same transaction:

```
      return transaction.set(countRef, {
        notifications: newNotification
      });
```